# PostgreSQL keeps drive active. How to debug?

Tags: hard-drive, postgresql

I run a small home server with Debian including a autoshutdown script if the system is idle. Since a few days my drives are not staying in standby and with this the server is always running.

I analysed this with `iotop -bktoqqq -d .5` and the following entry always shows up when the drives are going back from standby to active

```
rsyslogd -n -iNONE [rs:main Q:Reg]
postgres: 11/main: nextcloud_db_user nextcloud_db ::1(42284) idle
```

or

```
rsyslogd -n -iNONE [rs:main Q:Reg]
postgres: 11/main: nextcloud_db_user nextcloud_db ::1(34282) UPDATE
postgres: 11/main: nextcloud_db_user nextcloud_db ::1(34282) SELECT
```

Additional problem is that I have same or similar entries in my log as well where drives are staying in standby.

If I disable PostgreSQL service my drives are going in standby and the server shuts down as defined.

What could be the reason for these? My PostgreSQL database is not located on these 2 hard drives. Only data is.

How can I figure out which specific file is accessed at the time the log shows up?

Comment: What do [these commands](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/find-process-file-is-busy) show ?

Comment: So this is likely related to Nextcloud. Does your Nextcloud installation reside on the drives? Do you have any sync clients on any device? Or did you set up a cron integration for Nextcloud? Check your web server’s access log for hints.

Comment: @DanielB Yes, it is related to nextcloud. Problem is that I did not changed anything. So no New Clients compared to before. Also config is unchanged. But it worked for years. Therefore it can be only related to update of nextcloud vor PostgreSQL. But the issue is not known and therefore I look for ways to debug further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to further debug and to find the root cause. I now switched from PostgreSQL to MariaDB and now the drives are staying idle.